# The irreducible representations of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory

In Fulton's book, a irreducible representation of $\mathbb{C}S_n$ is of the form $\mathbb{C}S_nc_{\lambda}$. Here $\mathbb{C}S_nc_{\lambda}$ is just a complex vector space, but by the definition of group representation, group representation is a group homomorphism, then why is $\mathbb{C}S_nc_{\lambda}$ a group homomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are at least two ways really to define a linear representation of a finite group:

- A map $\phi:G\times V\to V$ on a vector space $V$ such that for every fixed $g\in G$, the assignment $v\mapsto \phi(g,v)$ is a linear map. In other words, a linear group action.
- A group homomorphism $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

The vector space $V$ may be called the carrier space of the representation. If the action of the group $G$ on the vector space is clear from context, or is an arbitrary action, then we may just call $V$ the representation even though technically the letter $V$ initially is reserved for the vector space.

So of course $\mathbb{C}S_nc_\lambda$ is not a group homomorphism, but it is a vector space and it is clear how $S_n$ acts on it: by left multiplication. Indeed, if we instead think of it as a representation of the complex group algebra $\mathbb{C}S_n$, or in other words a left module over it, then this is automatic. Given any algebra $A$ and left ideal $I\triangleleft A$, we know $I$ is automatically a left $A$-module using left multiplication, and in particular $\mathbb{C}S_nc_\lambda$ is a principal left ideal of $\mathbb{C}S_n$.